# Performance-maximizing retrieval of legal chess moves in c

Tags: arrays, c, performance, time, memory-efficient

I'm making a simple ASCII chess game in c for practice, as I'm new to the language. I'd like to create a function that returns some sort of list of possible chess moves. I can store the data for a single move within an integer, as 32 bits is more than enough to encode all the information I need for a single move. Hence, it seems reasonable to return an integer array. No problem here.

I have no problem finding the legal moves. The problem is, when generating this list, **I don't know what size or what datetype of array to initialize**. This is, of course, because the amount of possible legal moves per board state varies dramatically.

A simple solution would be to initialize an array that has a length greater than I'd ever need.

Pseudocode:

```
int[] legal_moves():
    int legals[1000];
    int index = 0;
    for (int move : moves):
        if (legal(move)) {
            legals[index] = move;
            index++;
        }
    return legals;
```

After filling this array with moves, there'd be many empty slots in the array. However this seems highly memory inefficient. Not that chess is a memory intensive game, I'd simply **like to get everything as relatively memory and time efficient and as possible** (as per why I'm using c). As I'm used to programming in python, lists can have arbitrary lengths, and there I'd simply 'append' a move; which isn't trivial in c.

Memory-efficiency is much less of a priority than time-efficiency, so if the previous approach is the most time-efficient; I'm happy with that. I'd like to hear your thoughts for different methods, however.

Comment: Why not find out how many moves are possible , and `malloc()` as many elements needed ?
Alternatively, you could just implement a trivial function that allows you to append to an array using `realloc()` and such too. I'm hesitant in posting this as an answer because I don't play chess, so I may be misinterpreting you.

Comment: @AnAnt Thanks for the insight. The only problem with initializing an array after finding out how many moves are possible, is that I'd have to loop through the board twice. Once to count how many moves, and once to then add those moves to the array of perfect size. Of course, I'd only need to loop once if during the 'counting moves' process I also stored them, but ironically storing is exactly what's needed to be accomplished. The `realloc` method seems appropriate, but I don't know how time-efficient reallocating memory after each 'append' is.

Comment: The options are: fixed sized array, linked list, or malloc/realloc. I'd go with the first since the array size is small.

Comment: @Graviton In C , you do not (ideally) `realloc()` one element after the other, just like you don't copy a file byte-by-byte but rather use some sort of buffer. You would ideally `malloc()` a reasonable amount of bytes (say 1KiB) to a pointer, then if you fill it, realloc a reasonable amount to the pointer (say 500 B) and do this again if you fill that too (in a loop). However, for anything so small , say less than a couple million bytes (1-2 MiB) , unless you are writing code for embedded devices, it would be easier as well as performant to use a fixed array.

Comment: @AnAnt Taking that into account, and considering that I'm working with data on the order of at most a couple hundred bytes, I think you're right with the best approach being a fixed array size.

Comment: @Graviton Brilliant then , use it. In fact , "*fixed*" arrays of such small size could likely be placed on the cache/registers (which `malloc()` , `realloc()` etc and `static` never can), which is the *fastest* place to store things.

Comment: @AnAnt That sounds quite optimal, would you guide me to a reference about using the cache/registers? I'm unfamiliar with working with them directly.

Comment: @Graviton The compiler and OS automatically decide which data resides on the cache, and they are reliable. You could hint to the compiler about this by using the `register` prefix , like `register uint_fast8_t buffer[BLOCK];` , but ultimately, with or without it, a modern compiler will do as necessary.

Comment: Is there any reason you chose C and not C++? You could get the same memory and performance efficiency, with much less effort.

Comment: The performance of your game will largely depend on the algorithm: how do you generate the array of possible moves, and how would you validate them (or generate only valid moves in the first place), not so much on how you allocate / reallocate an array of integers.

Comment: @VladFeinstein No reason in particular for C over C++. I'm simply more familiar with C, and with C being more functional-based rather than object-oriented (which seems to be my programming preference), It's my go-to low-level language. You're right, however that the algorithm will have the largest affect.

Comment: @Graviton - you probably mean `procedural`, not `functional`. I assure you that you can do the same in C++, while getting "free" containers, algorithm, etc. See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-c-and-c/